# Google drive upload an image from memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-drive-api

Good day,

I have this code which upload an image to Google drive from file, everything works well:

```
// Create a new file on Google Drive
 using (var fsSource = new FileStream(UploadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
      // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
      var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "image/jpg");
      request.Fields = "*";
      var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);
      
      }
```

Now I want to do some image manipulation before uploading so that I could convert the image to jpeg if the image is in another format (png or bmp for example) or resize the image, so I changed the file to stream for manipulation, I don't want to save it locally again because the code could be used on a website on mobiles, that's why I am saving to stream.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {

                Image img = Image.FromFile(uploadfileName);
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

How can I now upload this ms stream to Google Drive?
Thanks for any clue, I'm not an expect in field.

Comment: Just set `ms.Position = 0`, so that the next read starts reading from the beginning of the stream, then use it in place of your `fsSource` in your first snippet

Comment: Hi there! If the approach commented by @canton7 works for you, could you please write an answer for documentation purposes?

Comment: This particular question has been answered dozens of times before -- it would be better to link it to a duplicate

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron, Just did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for assistance.
The answer suggested by canton7 works:
Just set ms.Position = 0, so that the next read starts reading from the beginning of the stream, then use it in place of your fsSource in your first snippet